# Как сформировать подпись в платежной форме?

Tags: php

Привет!
Пытаюсь создать элементарную страницу оплаты через FREE KASSA.
Создаю код вида:

```
 <?php
              $merchant_id = '33643';
              $secret_word = 'uwrejyvi';
              $order_id = '154';
              $order_amount = '100';
              $sign = md5($merchant_id.':'.$order_amount.':'.$secret_word.':'.$order_id);
            ?>
              <form method='get' action='http://www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php'>
                  <input type='hidden' name='m' value='33643'>
                  <input type='hidden' name='oa' value='100'>
                  <input type='hidden' name='o' value='154'>
                  <input type='hidden' name='s' value='<?php $sign?>'>
                  <input type='hidden' name='i' value='94'>
                  <input type='hidden' name='lang' value='ru'>
    <button type="submit" name='pay' class="btn btn-primary">Перейти к оплате</button>
    </form>
```

Но получаю сообщение о неверно подписи. Где я совершаю ошибку?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка у Вас в том, что подпись просто не вставляется в код. Вы ошиблись в следующем участке кода:

```
<input type='hidden' name='s' value='<?php $sign?>'>
```

Данный код просто вызывает переменную sign. Для вывода переменной воспользуйтесь конструкцией echo.

```
<input type='hidden' name='s' value='<?php echo $sign;?>'>
```